# Fading in with jQuery creating a queue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a simple sequence: find first element, hide its siblings **and then fade it in**. I have this sort of working; however, it does not wait for its siblings to fade out first:

```
var $firstCaption = $('.caption').first();

$firstCaption.appendTo('.caption-content').siblings('.caption').fadeOut(function(){
     $firstCaption.fadeIn(); // this is not waiting
});
```

I could use a delay, but I think that's quite a messy solution? Is there another method?

JSFIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/8VjLD/

Comment: make a fiddle for that

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/8VjLD/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a promise:

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8VjLD/1/)

```
$('a').click(function () {
    var $firstCaption = $('.caption').first();
    $firstCaption.appendTo('.caption-content').siblings('.caption').fadeOut().promise().done(function () {
        $firstCaption.fadeIn();
    });
});
```

BTW, you could wish to use `.finish()` here if button clicked multiple times in a row:

[DEMO with finish](http://jsfiddle.net/8VjLD/2/)

```
$firstCaption.appendTo('.caption-content').siblings('.caption').finish()...
```

Comment: Really nice example that